# where to set background color?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-plot, candlestick-chart

i was just browsing the classes for an hour and cant find it! i started with searching the example of the AAPLot project.

i changed the graph a bit and was expecting to find all settings in the CPTTradingRangePlot class but it´s not there.

there are a lot of properties which i can change, but i can´t find the background settings in any of the classes.

could anybody give me a hint?

```
// OHLC plot
CPTMutableLineStyle *whiteLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
whiteLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
whiteLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
CPTTradingRangePlot *ohlcPlot = [[[CPTTradingRangePlot alloc] initWithFrame:graph.bounds] autorelease];
ohlcPlot.identifier = @"OHLC";
ohlcPlot.lineStyle = whiteLineStyle;
ohlcPlot.barWidth = 4.0f;
ohlcPlot.increaseFill = [(CPTFill *)[CPTFill alloc] initWithColor:[CPTColor greenColor]];
ohlcPlot.decreaseFill = [(CPTFill *)[CPTFill alloc] initWithColor:[CPTColor redColor]];
    CPTMutableTextStyle *whiteTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
whiteTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    whiteTextStyle.fontSize = 12.0;
    ohlcPlot.labelTextStyle = whiteTextStyle;
    ohlcPlot.labelOffset = 5.0;
ohlcPlot.stickLength = 2.0f;
ohlcPlot.dataSource = self;
ohlcPlot.plotStyle = CPTTradingRangePlotStyleCandleStick;
[graph addPlot:ohlcPlot];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found it by myself. the background of the chart is managed by a theme. there are several theme files in the folder theme of the core-plot library and one of them is CPTStocksTheme. The CPTStocksTheme creates a blue gradient background which can be changed there.

Comment: The best and easiest way is to do it like Chris Hodges example even though this does work.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a very simple example. This:

```c
CPTColor *your_color = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
your_graph.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:your_color];
```

will turn your graph's background red. But as Eric Skroch said, you may want to do this...

```c
your_graph.plotAreaFrame.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:your_color];
```

and / or this...

```c
your_graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:your_color];
```

depending on the result you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Backgrounds in Core Plot are set using `CPTFill` objects similar to the `increaseFill` and `decreaseFill` in your code sample. Depending on the look you want to achieve, you need to set the fill on `graph`, `graph.plotAreaFrame`, and/or `graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea`. The axis demo in the Mac version of CPTTestApp uses fills in all three areas so you can see the different parts.

Answer (score 1):

You may set it in xAxis or yAxis using CPTColor.

axisSet.yAxis.alternatingBandFills = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CPTColor redColor],
                            [CPTColor whiteColor], [CPTColor purpleColor], nil];